# Pivot Table Slow When Pivoting Using an Analysis Services Tabular Model

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas, ssas-tabular

Working in excel and querying an ssas tabular model works fine when we leave values in the columns. But when we have rows with high cardinality and place values in the rows to pivot the table (see image), it slows way down. This was not an issue when we were working with a multidimensional cube. Is there anything I can do to increase performance of the tabular model?
[Excel Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu53F.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to answer that question without knowing more details on your data model. Some things to consider:

- What are the cardinalities of the columns [ItemID] and [Item Description]? If the cardinalities are close to that of the table itself, maybe its better to use a [DetailRows (drill-through) report](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/controlling-drillthrough-using-detail-rows-expressions-in-dax/).
- Could you restrict the number of rows returned by putting a filter or a slicer on the Pivot Table?
- How complex is the DAX code of your two measures [Total Fcst Revenue] and [Total Promo $]? Maybe you can get much better performance by optimizing these two.
- What is the performance when you query the model using DAX, for example within DAX Studio or SSMS:

  ```
  EVALUATE
  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      Item[ItemID],
      Item[Item Description],
      "Total Fcst Revenue", [Total Fcst Revenue],
      "Total Promo $", [Total Promo $]
  )
  ```

  If the performance of a pure DAX query is considerably faster than an equivalent MDX query, you may be suffering the consequences of the [missing fusion optimization in MDX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/why-reports-obtained-with-analyze-in-excel-can-be-slower/).

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Excel have not kept pace with SSAS and will not perform well when pushed with increasing cardinality. PowerBI and Office 365 are very suitable and perform very well, whereas Excel 2010 is, in my very recent experience, no longer a viable front end.